How to validate same name category creation that already exits in database while creating crud REST API?
I am creating CRUD API for category and products, each category may have many products, but I want to validate that if for example category name "Grocery", I already added (exist in database) and again I am trying with the same name category add to the database it gives the error.
It gives me this error in POSTMAN:
{
    "message": "\nInvalid `db_util_1.default.category.create()` invocation in\nC:\\Users\\Ivtech-019\\Desktop\\express\\dist\\modules\\category\\cateogry.service.js:33:59\n\n  30 exports.getAllCategory = getAllCategory;\n  31 function createCategory(data) {\n  32     return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () {\n→ 33         const category = yield db_util_1.default.category.create(\nUnique constraint failed on the fields: (`name`)"
}

Now I want to handle this error, I want to write custom message that "This Category name is already exist" or something like this.
Technology I am using:
Typescript
Prisma
Postgres SQL
Express
Zod Error
